# setUpClass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I tried to use `setUpClass()` method for the first time in my life and wrote:

```
class TestDownload(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUpClass(cls):
        config.fs = True
```

and got:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 163, in _handleClassSetUp
    setUpClass()
TypeError: setUpClass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
```

What does it mean and how to satisfy it?

Comment: Did you put a `@classmethod` decorator before `def setUpClass(cls):` ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to put a `@classmethod` decorator before `def setUpClass(cls)`.

```
class TestDownload(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        config.fs = True
```

The [`setupClass` docs are here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) and [`classmethod` docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

What happens is that in [suite.py line 163](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/suite.py#L163) the `setUpClass` gets called on the class (not an instance) as a simple function (as opposed to a bound method). There is no argument passed silently to `setUpClass`, hence the error message.

By adding the `@classmethod` decorator, you are saying that when `TestDownload.setupClass()` is called, the first argument is the class `TestDownload` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Adding @classmethod before setUp and tearDown will resolve the issue. @classmethod is bound to the class.

```
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):

   **Your code**

   @classmethod
   def tearDownClass(self):
```

Comment: How does this complement the existing answer?